# Reply-to header in contact form PHP

Tags: php, forms, contacts

```
// Subject of your email
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] . ' - Personal website contact form submittion.'; 
// Recipient's E-mail
$to = 'recipient@domain.com';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
// Sender's E-mail
$headers .= "From: Contact Form (Domain.com) <no-reply@domain.com>"; 
$message .= 'Name: ' . $_REQUEST['name'] . "<br>";
$message .= 'Email: ' . $_REQUEST['email'] . "<br>";
$message .= 'Message: ' . $_REQUEST['message'] . "<br>";

if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    // Transfer the value 'sent' to ajax function for showing success message.
  echo 'sent';
} else {
  // Transfer the value 'failed' to ajax function for showing error message.
  echo 'failed';
}
```

How do I put reply-to header here?
Reply-to email should be the email that person enters while filling up the form, I don't know PHP can anyone help me out? thanks

Comment: exactly as you are with the rest of `$headers`... and if you're doing "complex" messages with mime and whatnot, you should be using a proper mailing package, like phpmailer or swiftmailer. php's built in `mail()` is basically a toy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] . ' - Personal website contact form submittion.'; // Subject of your email
$to = 'recipient@domain.com'; //Recipient's E-mail

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Contact Form (Domain.com) <no-reply@domain.com>\r\n"; // Sender's E-mail
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$_REQUEST['email']."<". $_REQUEST['email'].">\r\n" .
$message .= 'Name: ' . $_REQUEST['name'] . "<br>";
$message .= 'Email: ' . $_REQUEST['email'] . "<br>";
$message .= 'Message: ' . $_REQUEST['message'] . "<br>";

if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    // Transfer the value 'sent' to ajax function for showing success message.
    echo 'sent';
}
else
{
    // Transfer the value 'failed' to ajax function for showing error message.
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

Comment: can you help me add it to the code I mentioned above?

Comment: It's not working, after adding the code, the messages are not being sent.

Comment: I tried the updated code. It shows message could not be sent.

Comment: can u dump the stack trace?

Comment: Can you help me write a simple PHP code? This one is too complicated with mime and stuff.?

Comment: Here is the simplest example:
`<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>`

Comment: Worked! Modified code to: `$headers = 'From: nobody@example.com' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: '.$_REQUEST['email']. "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();`
and then it worked. Thanks! :)